# TKinter - how to add two figures from Entry()

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a calculator which adds to figures entered with Entry()
My current code returns no result - I see only fields and the button
Please help

```
from tkinter import *
a=Entry()
b=Entry()
def take():
    aa=float(a.get())
    bb=float(b.get())
    cc=aa+bb
root = Tk()
    Button(text="Calc", command=take).pack()
a.pack()
b.pack()
cc = Label(width=10, height=10)
cc.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`cc` is a Label object in the program, and the variable name is also locally used in the function `take`.

By assigning `cc=aa+bb` in the function, generates a local variable, but doesn't print this value on the root window.

To print the value, you need to `configure` the Label widget `cc` as:

```
cc.config(text=aa+bb) # Replace cc=aa+bb
```